# How to handle data loss via BLE on Samsung phones

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-firmware

The problem is that when the bluetooth signal strength is unstable and the bandwidth must be shared for audio, the BLE packet splitting mechanism occurs, this mechanism still exists even though the bluetooth signal has become stable again. Is there any way to remove this package splitting mechanism on Android? And if I can't uninstall it, is there any way to reconfigure the mechanism so that the packets don't split as before?

I tried increasing the request mtu to maximum and reducing the audio quality from 192 kbps to 80 kbps but the data loss still occurred.

My wish is is there a way to disable this packet splitting mechanism on Android when the BLE signal is poor? And if I can't turn it off, is there any way to reconfigure the mechanism so that packets are not split like before?

Comment: Exactly what "packet splitting mechanism" are your referring to that would cause data loss?